# Sencha touch 2 gives different UI on native android

Tags: android, html, sencha-touch-2

When I run my Sencha Touch 2 app on chrome and provide platform as android, Sencha gives perfect android UI, but as soon as I package the app as an apk and run on my Nexus 7, the app just tries to convert a few elements (drop down,switch,etc.) to native android UI, but rest of the UI including the tab bar, is shown as native iOS. Here is my css array in app.json:-

```
"css": [
  {
     "path": "resources/css/sencha-touch.css",
     "platform": [
        "desktop"
     ],
     "update": "delta"
  },
  {
     "path": "resources/css/wp.css",
     "platform": [
        "ie10"
     ],
     "theme": "Windows",
     "update": "delta"
  },
  {
     "path": "resources/css/mountainview.css",
     "platform": [
        "android"
     ],
     "theme": "Mountainview",
     "update": "delta"
  },
  {
     "path": "resources/css/cupertino.css",
     "platform": [
        "ios"
     ],
     "theme": "Cupertino",
     "update": "delta"
  },
  {
     "update": "delta",
     "platform": [
        "phone",
        "tablet",
        "desktop"
     ],
     "theme": "Cupertino",
     "path": "resources/css/cupertino.css",
     "_architect_active_theme": true
  }
]
```

Am I missing something somewhere else?

Comment: I know it is 3 years later now, but did you ever resolve this? I'm experiencing the same behaviour in Sencha Touch 2.3.1

Comment: Hi @jcaruso, This was posted 6 days ago (11th April) not 3 years ago. I am still not able to solve this. I have a workaround though, for native android I am compiling the apk with specifying only android as the theme. For other platforms I can have the above mentioned code(not tested with windows phone).

Comment: For some reason I read Apr 11 as 2011. By the way, I've been working with Sencha's premium support forums, I think I have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that when running on an Android device (or maybe just Android 4.4 devices) that both Android and Chrome are passed in as platforms. So in order to only load the Android theme, you need to exclude other platforms from the CSS array items in the app.json file.

Here is the CSS array I am using for my app which supports (and is currently working for) both Desktop, iOS and Android devices.

```
"css": [
        {
            "path": "resources/css/app.css",
            "platform": ["chrome", "ie10", "bb10", "desktop"],
            "exclude": ["ios", "ios-classic", "android"],
            "update": "delta"
        }, {
            "path": "resources/css/cupertino.css",
            "platform": ["ios", "ios-classic"],
            "exclude": ["chrome", "ie10", "bb10", "desktop", "android"],
            "theme": "Cupertino",
            "update": "delta"
        }, {
            "path": "resources/css/mountainview.css",
            "platform": ["android"],
            "exclude": ["ie10", "bb10", "desktop", "ios", "ios-classic"],
            "theme": "MountainView",
            "update": "delta"
        }]
```

Comment: Nope...doesn't work...is it because I am working with sencha architect? because when I save anything using the IDE, it changes app.json and the output is very weird. It's a mix of android and ios theme.

Comment: Might be, if Sencha Architect is changing that CSS array. I built my app and UI in a text editor so I didn't have to deal with that. Have you tried making the edits yourself then running the app just to see if you can get it to work outside of Sencha Architect?

Comment: Yes I did try that, but it was not working properly. Finally I had to build with specifying only mountainview css. Mountainview css does have a lot of other issues as well.

Comment: Can you post your css array, maybe I can take a look at it to see what might be going wrong.